Extracting the hessian/covariance matrix in gam (R package mgcv) including the parameter related to the dispersion of the distribution
When fitting gams in the package mgcv (with or without smoothers) I would like to extract the hessian matrix (or variance-covariance matrix) including the parameter related to the dispersion of the distribution (sigma in case of the normal, k in case of the negative binomial, phi in case of the beta etc). How can I get those? It seems that the function vcov only extracts parameters related to the mean of the distribution.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
a minimal example with the beta distribution is shown below:
# generate data
set.seed(30);
n <- 200
x <- runif(n, 0, 5)
mu <- exp(-4+1*x)/(1 + exp(-4+1*x))
phi <- 4
a <- mu*phi; b <- (1-mu)*phi;
y <- rbeta(n, shape1=a, shape2=b) 
dat <- data.frame(x, y)
# fit model with betareg package
library(betareg)
br1 <- betareg(y ~ x, data=dat)
logLik(br1)
vcov(br1)
# fit model with mgcv package
library(mgcv)
bm <- gam(y ~ x, family=betar(link="logit"), 
              data=dat)
summary(bm)
logLik(bm)
vcov(bm)


In some cases I would guess that the scale parameter (e.g. sigma in the case of the normal) would be estimated from the residual deviance rather than being estimated directly (e.g. this is how dispersion parameters are derived in glm), but it's hard to see how that could be the case for cases like the negative binomial ...

Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.
